# Scale image up using imageresizer

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am processing images using the ImageResizer library. All of the images vary in size and I want to create normalized renditions of them. Say:

- 40 x 40
- 120 x 120
- 400 x 400

etc...

So - when an image comes in that is 100 x 100 - how can I scale that image up so that I end up with 120 x  120 and 400 x 400?

Atm if the image is smaller than the resize dimensions it seems to leave the image alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To upscale OR downscale the image (resulting in blurriness), use `scale=both`.
- To upscale the canvas and leave the original photo at 1:1, use `scale=canvas1.
- To upscale *only*, never downscaling, use `scale=up`.

Check out [ImageResizer Basics](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics) for some visual examples.

Comment: Actually was a combination of  Mode = FitMode.Max, Scale = ScaleMode.Both